# Is it possible to detect if the page is being iframed by a specific domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible test if the page is being iframed by a specific domain with JavaScript?

Like this:

```
if (window!=window.top){
   if (this page is iframed by www.foo.com){ // load foo's special navigation bar}
   if (this page is iframed by www.bar.com){ // load bar's special navigation bar}
} else { //load normal navigation bar }
```

Comment: Maybe have access to `window.top.location`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var parentLocation='';
if(window.parent && document.referrer)
    parentLocation = document.referrer;
alert(parentLocation);
```

You should see the parent page's url in the alert box. And the rest, as they say, is history...

Comment: Excellent answer.  I am going to delete mine as your code works!  @Dave - you should select this as the answer as it will solve your problem; however, keep in mind that you still won't have access to the DOM.

Comment: This does not appear to work if window.parent is served from a "https:" (secure) url.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT/UPDATE:** Although it *is possible* to get the domain name of the parent iframe, I didn't want to delete this answer as there is some helpful information for understanding the same domain policy in terms of accessing the DOM. Soumya92's answer proves that an iframe on one domain can indeed retrieve the domain of the parent domain.

However, the other information regarding DOM access still holds true.

### Original Answer

Unfortunately, this is just not yet possible in most browsers, and it's definitely not possible unless both websites have given the other domains permission to access each domain's data by setting the `document.domain` property.  Even then, it will only work with sub-domains.

For instance, `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` can access each other's DOM as long as **both** HTML pages have set the `document.domain` property like so:

```
// allow foo.example.com and bar.example.com to communicate
document.domain = "example.com";
```

If you are trying to check to see if `www.foo.com` is the parent of a document loaded from `www.bar.com`, you will not be able to do this as the iframe will not have access to `top.window`.

You could determine if the iframe is being loaded in the same domain, and use powers of deduction to determine that it is not loaded from the same domain when a same domain policy error is encountered.

Beyond that, you will not be able to determine any specifics regarding which domain is loading your document.

Comment: For example I have 3 sites that will always be viewed as such: foo.com, bar.com, and example.com. All the sites are hosted as subdomains, so they also exist as foo.example.com, bar.example.com, and example.com, but never get viewed this way. Can your example work with my "set up".

Comment: @Dave - You could use a rewrite rule to force the domains to redirect to the subdomains.  That would be the only way.  For instance, `local.sandbox.com` and `local.sandbox2.com` are the same folder on my Apache server (ServerAliases), but the example from @Zoidberg only works if I use the same domain (or a subdomain with `document.domain`).  If I wanted to allow communication between `local.sandbox` and `local.sandbox2`, I would have to rewrite one of them to match the other.  That is the **only** way to do this with the current technologies.  Note, rewriting involves domain ownership.